# Re-writing a SQL Server Stored proc in Postgres to return sets of data to client

Tags: postgresql

I am in processing of migrating a SQL Server database to Postgres and this has mean re-writing
the stored procedures in Postgres.

I am new to postgres development and trying to get my head round , how i can return mutiple
selects

We have to do this ..as the client is passing back mutiple recordsets to a  C Sharp application

My tables definitions as as follows:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.device
(
    deviceid uuid NOT NULL,
    serialnumber character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    productcode character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    softwareversion character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    build character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    builddate timestamp with time zone,
    assigned boolean,
    groupid uuid,
    updateddatetime timestamp with time zone,
    restartpointerno integer,
    deviceconnectionindex integer,
    organisationid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT pk__device__49e123311461d246 PRIMARY KEY (deviceid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_device_organisation_organisationid FOREIGN KEY (organisationid)
        REFERENCES dbo.organisation (organisationid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice951246 FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice_deviceconnectiontype FOREIGN KEY (deviceconnectionindex)
        REFERENCES dbo.deviceconnectiontype (deviceconnectionindex) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device
    OWNER to postgres;


-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.groups;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.groups
(
    groupid uuid NOT NULL,
    groupname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    groupparentid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT pk__groups__149af30a383c48d4 PRIMARY KEY (groupid),
    CONSTRAINT fkgroups635827 FOREIGN KEY (groupparentid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.groups
    OWNER to postgres;

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.devicechannel;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.devicechannel
(
    devicechannelid uuid NOT NULL,
    deviceid uuid,
    groupid uuid,
    channeltypeid uuid,
    derivedchannelid uuid,
    channelid integer,
    channelname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    isinternal boolean,
    dimension character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    symbol character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    upper real,
    lower real,
    "precision" integer,
    conversiontypeid smallint,
    CONSTRAINT pk__devicech__b0754e8587c246f2 PRIMARY KEY (devicechannelid),
    CONSTRAINT devicechannel_deviceid_channelid UNIQUE (deviceid, channelid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice_devicechannel FOREIGN KEY (deviceid)
        REFERENCES dbo.device (deviceid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan248448 FOREIGN KEY (channeltypeid)
        REFERENCES dbo.channeltype (channeltypeid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan30310 FOREIGN KEY (conversiontypeid)
        REFERENCES dbo.conversiontype (conversiontypeid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan3820 FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan92763 FOREIGN KEY (derivedchannelid)
        REFERENCES dbo.derivedchannel (derivedchannelid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.devicechannel
    OWNER to postgres;

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.channeltype;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.channeltype
(
    channeltypeid uuid NOT NULL,
    description character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    comments character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    channeltypeindex integer,
    CONSTRAINT pk__channelt__5aca2b38f1f89edb PRIMARY KEY (channeltypeid)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.channeltype
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Now my function so far looks like this

```
DROP FUNCTION spGetDeviceInventory_Main();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spGetDeviceInventory_Main(s2 text)

DO $$
  
DECLARE     RC                      INT;
    
DECLARE     GroupID2                UUID;
DECLARE     DeviceID2               UUID;

/*********************** 
* Initialise Variables *
***********************/

    SET RC                      = 0

    IF S2 IS NULL

        BEGIN
            SELECT
                DeviceID,
                SerialNumber,
                ProductCode,
                Description,
                SoftwareVersion,
                Build,
                BuildDate,
                Assigned,
                GroupID,
                DeviceConnectionIndex       
            FROM dbo.Device;

            SELECT
                GroupID,
                GroupName,
                GroupParentID
            FROM dbo.Groups;

            SELECT
                DeviceChannelID,
                DeviceID,
                GroupID,
                 dc.ChannelTypeID,
                DerivedChannelID,
                ChannelID,
                ChannelName,
                IsInternal,
                Dimension,
                Symbol,
                Upper,
                Lower,
                Precision,
                ct.ChannelTypeIndex
            FROM
                dbo.DeviceChannel dc
                    left join
                dbo.ChannelType ct on dc.ChannelTypeID = ct.ChannelTypeID;

            /*************************************************************************************************************************************************** 
            *                                               TAGS                                                                                            *
            ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/

            SELECT
                TagID,
                NodeID,
                TagName
            FROM dbo.Tag;

        END

    ELSE

        BEGIN
              SELECT
                DeviceID,
                SerialNumber,
                ProductCode,
                Description,
                SoftwareVersion,
                Build,
                BuildDate,
                Assigned,
                GroupID
            FROM dbo.Device
            WHERE SerialNumber = s2;


         
            -- Get the groupID
            SELECT GroupID =GroupID
            FROM dbo.Device
            WHERE SerialNumber = s2;

            SELECT
                GroupID,
                GroupName,
                GroupParentID
            FROM dbo.Groups
            WHERE GroupID = GroupID;

           
            -- get the deviceID
            SELECT DeviceID =DeviceID
            FROM dbo.Device
            WHERE SerialNumber = s2;

            SELECT
                DeviceChannelID,
                DeviceID,
                GroupID,
                dc.ChannelTypeID,
                DerivedChannelID,
                ChannelID,
                ChannelName,
                IsInternal,
                Dimension,
                Symbol,
                Upper,
                Lower,
                Precision,
                ct.ChannelTypeIndex
            FROM
                dbo.DeviceChannel dc
                    left join
                dbo.ChannelType ct on dc.ChannelTypeID = ct.ChannelTypeID
            WHERE DeviceID = DeviceID2;
        END

END $$;
```

The intention is that s2 (which is Serial Number) is passed in as an input parameter

Now if that is null, then I want to return 3 selects from the tables dbo.Device, dbo.Groups, dbo.DeviceChannel
(Lines 22-60)

Then if s2 isnt null then its used to filter and return data from the differnet tables

This is quite straightforward to write in t-sql  however its more tricky in postgres because you have to delclare
exaactly all the columns and data types you want to return.

How can i do this in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

The `RETURNS TABLE` syntax in PostgreSQL lets you to format and return data according to particular constraints. It also allows you to design functions that return numerous result sets. Based on the input parameter `s2`, your function can return a variety of result sets. The function can use the `RETURN QUERY` statement to retrieve data from the `dbo.device`, `dbo.groups`, and `dbo.devicechannel` tables when `s2` is `NULL`. On the other hand, when `s2` contains a value, the function can filter data based on the `SerialNumber` and provide pertinent data from these tables. An example of this notion in code is provided here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spGetDeviceInventory_Main(s2 text)
RETURNS TABLE (
    deviceid uuid,
    serialnumber character varying,
    productcode character varying,
    description character varying,
    -- ... (other columns)
) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF s2 IS NULL THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT
            deviceid,
            serialnumber,
            productcode,
            description
            -- ... (other columns)
        FROM dbo.device;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY SELECT
            deviceid,
            serialnumber,
            productcode,
            description
            -- ... (other columns)
        FROM dbo.device
        WHERE serialnumber = s2;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When obtaining data for your C# application, this function structure can be useful because it enables you to collect various kinds of information from your PostgreSQL databases depending on the value of `s2`.

Comment: Hi Muhammed

thank  you very much for that

However if I want to add other selects into each section?

'''